# Accessible microstates of harmonic oscillator in microcanonical enemble

Tags: statistical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, partition-function

While reading up on statistical physics, I am going through the calculation of the partition function of the harmonic oscillator in the [microcanonical ensemble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcanonical_ensemble). The result for the partition function is:

$\Omega(E) = \frac{E_o}{\hbar \omega}$,

i.e. all one-dimensional harmonic oscillators of the same frequency $\omega$ have the same number of accessible microstates. Consequently, as $\omega$ grows, $\Omega(E)$ goes to zero. This is somewhat counter-intuitive to me. I would have expected that an oscillator with a higher frequency $\omega$ would have more accessible microstates than one with a lower frequency. What is wrong with my intuition?

Note that I am going through the classical calculation, the partition for the harmonic oscillator is then given as:

$\Omega(E) = \frac{E_0}{h}\int dp \int dx \delta \left( \frac{p^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2}k x^2 - E\right)  $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classical calculation goes like this.  Consider the Hamiltonian of the classical harmonic oscillator
$$
  H(q,p) = \frac{p^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 x^2
$$
The expression $\Omega(E)$ refers to the volume of the region in phase space corresponding to classical states $(q,p)$ with energies less than or equal to $E$, namely it is the volume of the interior of the ellipse specified by
$$
  \frac{p^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 x^2\leq E
$$
The volume (area in this case) of the interior of this ellipse turns out to be $E/\hbar\omega$.  One way to get intuition for this is that since $\omega^2$ multiplies $x^2$ in the hamiltonian, the ellipse constraint written above is satisfied only by points in phase space with *smaller* values of $x$ when you *increase* omega.  This should become even more transparent if you actually perform the ellipse area calculation.

Comment: Why does the delta turn into an inequality? I thought we wanted to integrate along the (x, p) surface for which H(x, p) exactly equals E...